# Thunderbird 3.1.7 notification on main monitor

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, thunderbird

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 with dual monitors. I laptop monitor is the main monitor and have a secondary monitor as extended.

Currently, my Thunderbird notifications appear on the secondary monitor where it's not easily noticeable. Is it possible to change which monitor the notification appears? I tried looking for a setting and plugin but no luck.

Thanks